# Permission Denied with python Bokeh library (in virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv, bokeh

[Python, Jupyter, Ubuntu 16]

I have a python3.5 virtualenv, to which I installed `bokeh`. I can import, define a graph just fine with:

```
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'petal len'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'petal width'
p.circle(flowers['petal_length'], flowers['petal_width'], color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)
```

but when I call `show(p)` I get the following:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-52ee71fc1db5> in <module>()
      2 p.yaxis.axis_label = 'petal width'
      3 p.circle(flowers['petal_length'], flowers['petal_width'], color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)
----> 4 show(p)

/home/USERNAME/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in show(obj, browser, new, notebook_handle)
    298     if obj not in _state.document.roots:
    299         _state.document.add_root(obj)
--> 300     return _show_with_state(obj, _state, browser, new, notebook_handle=notebook_handle)
    301 
    302 

/home/USERNAME/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new, notebook_handle)
    316 
    317     if state.file or not shown:
--> 318         _show_file_with_state(obj, state, new, controller)
    319 
    320     return comms_handle

/home/USERNAME/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in _show_file_with_state(obj, state, new, controller)
    321 
    322 def _show_file_with_state(obj, state, new, controller):
--> 323     filename = save(obj, state=state)
    324     controller.open("file://" + filename, new=_new_param[new])
    325 

/home/USERNAME/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in save(obj, filename, resources, title, state, validate)
    380 
    381     filename, resources, title = _get_save_args(state, filename, resources, title)
--> 382     _save_helper(obj, filename, resources, title, validate)
    383     return os.path.abspath(filename)
    384 

/home/USERNAME/ve/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in _save_helper(obj, filename, resources, title, validate)
    447         html = standalone_html_page_for_models(obj, resources, title)
    448 
--> 449         with io.open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    450             f.write(decode_utf8(html))
    451 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.html'
```

I tried `chown -R 755 /usr/lib/python3.5` to no avail. `~/virtualenv/lib/python3.5` is (weirdly) mostly 777, but it's like that on a fresh install too so I guess that's intentional.

Comment: Did you call `output_notebook` (for inline plots) or `output_file` (to specify the location to save to explicitly)?

Comment: Nope, that fixed it!! That is a rather surprising issue! Mind posting this as the answer?

Comment: In the next `0.12.5` release things are changed to use an OS-provided tempfile if the current location is not write-able (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5942), so the the point is probably moot. In any case I aways recommend using `output_file` explicitly (all the examples and documentation demonstrate this practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always advised to use `output_file` or `output_notebook` to explicitly state where output should be shown from. For inline plots in a Jupyter notebook, `output_notebook` is in fact *required* because that is the command that loads the necessary BokehJS library into the notebook. Without specifying either of these, Bokeh will attempt to save to an HTML file and then show. Prior to `0.12.5` Bokeh would attempt to use the current module name to infer a location, which could cause the problem seen above in some cases. After `0.12.5` Bokeh will use an OS-provided tempfile location which is guaranteed to be writable.